# Why java newInstance hang at getDeclaredConstructors0?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, rhino

We use mozlia rhino to generate dynamic class, then load JsClass by custom classloader like this

```
DynamicClassLoader loader = new DynamicClassLoader(JavaScriptFactory.class.getClassLoader());
Class<?> jsClass = loader.loadClass("D://","com.huawei.xxx");
jsClass.newInstance();
```

As you see, every JsClass have a seperate classloader, when user modify js, we will also reload JsClass by this code,

Now, we face a problem, when call jsClass.newInstance(), some thread hang at getDeclaredConstructors0 for a long time(3s-1000s), normally it shoud be less then 10ms. Can someone tell me the possiable reason? Thanks very much!

**JDK:**
1.8.0.60

**Tomcat:**
7.0.59

**JvmArgs:**

```
-Dnop -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -DDN=mateinfo_app -server -Duser.timezone=GMT -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/opt/mateinfo/logs/app/tomcat-gc-20160601-233343.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/mateinfo/logs/app/oom-20160601-233343.bin -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./deal-oom.sh -Xms3260m -Xmx3260m -Xmn800m -XX:MetaspaceSize=800m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=800m -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -Xverify:all -Dsoapui.log4j.config=/opt/mateinfo/app/lib/log4j.properties -Dlog4j.ignoreTCL=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8050 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/mateinfo/app/endorsed -classpath /opt/mateinfo/app/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/mateinfo/app/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/mateinfo/app -Dcatalina.home=/opt/mateinfo/app -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/mateinfo/app/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

**Thread Dump:**

```
----------------- 7123 -----------------
0x00007f9d44cdc6d5       __pthread_cond_wait + 0xc5
0x00007f9d43cc157c       _ZN15JvmtiRawMonitor11SimpleEnterEP6Thread + 0xdc
0x00007f9d43cc1c07       _ZN15JvmtiRawMonitor9raw_enterEP6Thread + 0xd7
0x00007f9d43c9a2ed      _ZN8JvmtiEnv15RawMonitorEnterEP15JvmtiRawMonitor + 0xad
0x00007f9d429c4df8       debugMonitorEnter + 0x38
0x00007f9d429b1451      event_callback + 0x2e1
0x00007f9d429b1e8e      cbClassPrepare + 0x8e
0x00007f9d43cb0beb      _ZN11JvmtiExport18post_class_prepareEP10JavaThreadP5Klass + 0x15b
0x00007f9d43b59f31       _ZN13InstanceKlass15link_class_implE19instanceKlassHandlebP6Thread + 0x3f1
0x00007f9d43b5a0d4      _ZN13InstanceKlass10link_classEP6Thread + 0x54
0x00007f9d43c3ec49       _ZL33get_class_declared_methods_helperP7JNIEnv_P7_jclasshbP5KlassP6Thread + 0xc9
0x00007f9d43c3f28e       JVM_GetClassDeclaredConstructors + 0xce

"app-JavaScriptFactory-7-thread-1" #41621 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9d1d7f9800 nid=0x1bd3 runnable [0x00007f9c8040e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
         at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
         at com.huawei.sdm.integration.message.runtime.handler.script.JsBeanGenerateRunner.excute(JsBeanGenerateRunner.java:82)
         at com.huawei.mateinfo.context.support.CommonCallable.call(CommonCallable.java:31)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**GCLog:**

```
{Heap before GC invocations=331320 (full 1587):
par new generation   total 773696K, used 732120K [0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000726400000, 0x0000000726400000)
  eden space 728192K, 100% used [0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000720b20000)
  from space 45504K,   8% used [0x0000000723790000, 0x0000000723b66170, 0x0000000726400000)
  to   space 45504K,   0% used [0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000723790000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2519040K, used 2123204K [0x0000000726400000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
Metaspace       used 341907K, capacity 402760K, committed 687488K, reserved 1640448K
  class space    used 38870K, capacity 47018K, committed 95616K, reserved 1048576K
2016-05-31T12:47:08.303+0000: 550384.634: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2016-05-31T12:47:08.303+0000: 550384.634: [ParNew: 732120K->2438K(773696K), 0.0228934 secs] 2855324K->2125771K(3292736K), 0.0231999 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
Heap after GC invocations=331321 (full 1587):
par new generation   total 773696K, used 2438K [0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000726400000, 0x0000000726400000)
  eden space 728192K,   0% used [0x00000006f4400000, 0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000720b20000)
  from space 45504K,   5% used [0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000720d81bc8, 0x0000000723790000)
  to   space 45504K,   0% used [0x0000000723790000, 0x0000000723790000, 0x0000000726400000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2519040K, used 2123332K [0x0000000726400000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
Metaspace       used 341907K, capacity 402760K, committed 687488K, reserved 1640448K
  class space    used 38870K, capacity 47018K, committed 95616K, reserved 1048576K
}
2016-05-31T12:47:08.334+0000: 550384.665: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 2123332K(2519040K)] 2135637K(3292736K), 0.0151574 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2016-05-31T12:47:08.349+0000: 550384.681: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
{Heap before GC invocations=331321 (full 1588):
par new generation   total 773696K, used 730630K [0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000726400000, 0x0000000726400000)
  eden space 728192K, 100% used [0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000720b20000)
  from space 45504K,   5% used [0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000720d81bc8, 0x0000000723790000)
  to   space 45504K,   0% used [0x0000000723790000, 0x0000000723790000, 0x0000000726400000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2519040K, used 2123332K [0x0000000726400000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
Metaspace       used 341907K, capacity 402760K, committed 687488K, reserved 1640448K
  class space    used 38870K, capacity 47018K, committed 95616K, reserved 1048576K
2016-05-31T12:47:09.419+0000: 550385.751: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-05-31T12:47:09.419+0000: 550385.751: [ParNew: 730630K->11995K(773696K), 0.0311341 secs] 2853963K->2135459K(3292736K), 0.0314510 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
Heap after GC invocations=331322 (full 1588):
par new generation   total 773696K, used 11995K [0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000726400000, 0x0000000726400000)
  eden space 728192K,   0% used [0x00000006f4400000, 0x00000006f4400000, 0x0000000720b20000)
  from space 45504K,  26% used [0x0000000723790000, 0x0000000724346f10, 0x0000000726400000)
  to   space 45504K,   0% used [0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000720b20000, 0x0000000723790000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2519040K, used 2123463K [0x0000000726400000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
Metaspace       used 341907K, capacity 402760K, committed 687488K, reserved 1640448K
  class space    used 38870K, capacity 47018K, committed 95616K, reserved 1048576K
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but my app would break on this same line in Class.java when debugging. I deleted all my breakpoints and it no longer stops there in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the application is running under debugger. Thread Dump indicates that the thread is hung inside JDWP agent.

Try to disable debugger. Alternatively you may turn on JDWP logging by adding the following agent options:

```
logfile=/path/to/jdwp.log,logflags=255
```

Comment: Yes, I turned on debug port but no Xdebug option(full jvm options already posted on question), because I think it will not effect application when nobody is debugging on it. It seems I'm wrong, right?

Comment: @zhufeizzz Yes, jdwp agent performs certain instrumentation even when debugger is not connected. This hang might be caused by an agent bug. Please try adding the above logging options to `-Xrunjdwp`. This may shed light on the problem.

Comment: I removed debug port, and never hanged again, tks!